# How does Kafka assign partitions to multiple brokers?

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's say we have two brokers (b1 and b2) and a topic created with 3 partiotions (p1, p2, p3) and replication factor is 2 (let's don't worry about replication factor for now, and below we only talk about leader partitions). So how How does Kafka assign partitions to multiple brokers e.g (b1 has p1, p2 and b2 has p3) OR (b2 has p1, p2 and b1 has p3) OR (b1 has p1, p3 and b2 has p2)?
Is the assignment determined by kafka internal algorithm? Is the assignment algorithm is a simple one like each broker has (numberOfPartitions)/(numberOfBrokers) and last broker has one partition depending on quotient result? can it be configured manually by clients?

Answer (score 0):

I believe replica placement was modeled after Hadoop datanodes. One leader broker from the cluster is selected, at random, then `broker.rack` is used (if configured) to place a rack-local replica, then all remaining replicas are placed at random on remaining nodes. Partitions themselves are distribued throughout the cluster evenly, from what I've seen in practice.

Some details are here, but not the algorithm itself - https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/architecture/data-replication/

> can it be configured manually by clients

Not directly. You can use `kafka-reassign-partitions` after the partitions (and replicas) have been decided and placed by the internal algorithm.